# Share Action provider not working

Tags: android

I have created an Android app.
It has a main activity (with fragment) and a detailed activity (with fragment)
In the detailed activity fragment, I want to add a share button which will share some fixed text (say - "Hello").
The share button appears in the app but nothing happens when I click it.
I want to share plain fixed text.

Here is the menu_detail.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android:support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

And here is the DetailActivityFragment.java file:

```
package com.blogspot.amangoeliitb.amansblog;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = DetailActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public DetailActivityFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider =
                (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        if(mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        }
        else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share action provider is null");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String title = extras.getString("TITLE") ;
        String content = extras.getString("CONTENT") ;
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.post_title)).setText(title);
        ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.post_content)).loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");

        return rootView;
    }

    private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
        return shareIntent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on the same problem.

There is a minute error in your code in menu_detail.xml file. In this line

**app:actionProviderClass="android:support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"**

Remove the ":" after android and replace with a full stop. So it should be

**app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"**

Everything else is good. And it is working for me.